# bcrypt-ruby won't install with bundler but works fine with gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, bcrypt

I just recently began having trouble with bundler - bcrypt-ruby will not install when doing a bundle install or sudo bundle install and exits with the following error:

```
Installing bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 

Gem files will remain installed in /home/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/deploy/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '2.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

However, `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '2.1.4'` runs just fine (and in fact has already been run on this box). Running `/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb` manually works just fine, and the resulting Makefile also runs with make just fine.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and bundler 1.0.21 on Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS. Other gems seem to be working fine through bundler. Though this is probably obvious, I've confirmed that the ruby-dev, gcc, etc packages are installed. I've tried using the --deployment option with bundler with no different behavior. The only thing I can think that has changed recently is I did a bundle update a couple days ago, so bundle got a minor version change (1.0.10 -> 1.0.21) and bcrypt appears to have gotten a major version change (2.1.4 -> 3.0.1).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As a couple added data points, I appear to have worked around this problem (though I don't really consider this a solution): I specified the old version of bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4) in my Gemfile and I also did a bundle --deployment (on a Mac OS X 10.7 installation - dev box), then on my Ubuntu test box, and it "worked". 

I suspect I would still have a problem with bcrypt 3.0.1, and I'm not sure why --deployment would help given the apparent problem is with native extensions, so doing this across architectures probably doesn't really help.

Answer (score 7):

Have you upgraded to Lion since you installed Ruby 1.9.2? If so it is probably linked to the wrong gcc.

Try uninstalling and reinstalling 1.9.2, I would suggest using [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)

```
rvm uninstall 1.9.2

rvm install 1.9.2
```

If that does not work you might have to implode rvm

```
rvm implode

bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)

source ~/.bash_profile

rvm install 1.9.2
```

Comment: Reinstalling ruby after lion upgrade fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```