# Can't install bcrypt-ruby for new Rails installation

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I'm getting the following error on a new Rails installation. I run `bundle install` and after installing a bunch of gems, I get an error upon trying to install bcrypt-ruby. I'm using a brand new Mac with OS X 10.8.2, latest Ruby (v1.9.3-p194), new Rails (v3.2.8) and standard Gemfile.

> Installing activerecord (3.2.8)
>
> Installing activeresource (3.2.8)
>
> Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb  creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make compiling bcrypt_ext.c make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or
>   directory make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@mygemset/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@mygemset/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

***UPDATE***: Forgot to mention, not only in this a brand new Mac with Mac OS X 10.8.2, but also brand new Xcode installed yesterday and with command line tools. I then installed RVM and brew.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968330/why-wont-the-bcrypt-ruby-gem-install-properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems odd on a brand new Mac, with new OS and new RVM installation that I would need to do this.. but what worked was simply linking gcc-4.2 to gcc:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following worked

```
gem uni bcrypt-ruby
gem i bcrypt-ruby --platform=ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded to Lion since you installed Ruby 1.9.3? If so it is probably linked to the wrong gcc.

Try uninstalling and reinstalling 1.9.3, I would suggest using rvm

```
rvm uninstall 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```

If that does not work you might have to implode rvm

```
rvm implode
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
source ~/.bash_profile
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: It looks to me like you don't have make on your system. If you're using a Mac, you need to install the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Updated question to state that Xcode command line tools were installed.

Comment: If you are going to copy / paste someone else's answer, atleast give credit http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084811/442695