# Why won't the bcrypt ruby gem install properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I am trying to encorporate bcrypt-ruby, v. 3.0.1.  I enter the gem in my gem file as follows:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
```

And I then go to the terminal and run:

```
bundle install
```

I get the following response:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/philip7899/.bundler/tmp/2186/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/philip7899/.bundler/tmp/2186/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am extremely new to both Ruby and Rails and have no idea how to fix this.  I have seen other stackoverflow pages with similar questions but none have been able to help me.  I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion and was told that could be an issue.  I was told to use RVM to uninstall and then reinstall Ruby.  I tried that and it did not work.

Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include the contents of `/Users/philip7899/.bundler/tmp/2186/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650773/cant-install-bcrypt-ruby-for-new-rails-installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing `,'3.0.1'` or try like this `gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.1"`

Hope it helps.

If not, from console try running `gem install bcrypt`

Comment: Then I just can forward you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119153/why-do-i-get-a-bcrypt-ruby-gem-install-error).

Comment: The combination of your answer plus the link you sent me (which I had tried before) worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `bcrypt-ruby` has been renamed to `bcrypt`: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby#how-to-install-bcrypt. So: `gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.1"`.

Comment: @Adobe Thanks! Updated the answer

Answer (score 26):

In recent versions `bcrypt-ruby` seems to use the GMP library.

So, on Linux something like this should help (command for Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo aptitude install libgmp-dev
```

Comment: Thanks @Envek, you have saved my lots of time.

Answer (score 4):

Actually a simple:

```
gem install bundler
gem install bcrypt-ruby
```

and then:

```
bundle update bcrypt-ruby
or bundle update bcrypt
```

Would've done the trick.

It's much the same way that you would upgrade rails. If you wanted to make sure you could also specify the latest bcrypt-ruby in your Gemfile. I just did this ten minutes ago so I know it works as of the date of this post... I was using ruby 1.9.3 p484

Comment: `gem install bundler` worked for me. Thank you! @mystic-cola

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a problem of xcode upgrade.

My solution:

```
brew install apple-gcc42
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

and it works

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix my issue with installing Bcrypt 3.1.11 gem which was failing with:

```
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.bundle
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adrian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
```

The problem was the `libgmp` wasn't found. First, install it via brew:

```
brew install gmp
```

Next, ensure that gcc will find the libraries by setting the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

And install:

```
gem install bcrypt
```

Comment: I've tried so many things to get this to succeed. Exporting the library path solved it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run the following command on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add the required gem to Gemfile
2. add this line to your config file if the remote path for bundle install has spaces:
   .bundle\config:

BUNDLE_LOCAL__BCRYPT: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.10\lib

3. run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple solution that worked for me:

Tested on mac:

Ensure that `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'` is in your gemfile then run `xcode-select --install`.
Run `bundle install`

That's it.

Best of lucks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. I resolved it by stopping my server and running bundle install. Make sure your server is not running while executing the command `bundle install`

Answer (score -2):

Gems with extensions written in C, like bcrypt, won't always compile on different platforms/ruby versions. You could look for a pure ruby alternative to bcrypt and avoid possible issues with C extensions altogether. You could also try a different version of the gem and see if it compiles on your system.

Comment: Thanks, I need to use this version though because the tutorial I have (huge book that I am midway through) uses this and I am not advanced enough to go off book.

Comment: What OS are you using? I've had the best results for C extensions using MRI on a Unix-like OS.

Comment: I'm using OSX Mountain Lion